# Touch events on Android are ignored in browser (rachet)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I am playing around with rachet for a web app. For some reason I cannot get touch events to work. I want the user to type in an `input` and dynamically return results based on that input. Works fine on desktop chrome ..

```
  $( "#chain1_query" ).on('touchend keyup', function() { 
  alert(("#chain1_query").val()) 
  ...
```

chucked a whole lot of events in there, I have tried each individually but no go.

Comment: Are other events not working too, or just those? Also ur alert has wrong jquery syntax, selectors have to be the same so wrap it with $(" ")

Comment: `click` seems to work ok.